# How to access or read document id from collection in index.js file from firestore?

Tags: android, node.js, push-notification, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I have document (Users) .Each user has document id and each document id has field like token id in a firestore. I am writing a function in index.js file for pushnotification. How can I read document id (id of each users) without triggering any read ,write ,update operation in firestore?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, what you want is not possible.

You cannot really get data from Firestore without performing any read operations.

Based on your description of the data model, I understand you have the following:

```
Users(Document)/document_id(map)/token_id(field)
```

If this is the case, getting all the `document_id` maps and `token_id` fields will be only 1 read operation. Every Document read is considered 1 read operation.

You can see [more details here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing#operations).

But if your data model is:

```
Users(Collection)/User(Document)/document_id(map)/token_id(field)
```

Then you need to read every User Document to get the data.

If the 2nd is your case, then you might want to have some relation between the document_id at the time of creation.

> (eg. id1 = X, id2 = id+101, id3 = id2+101)

This way by reading only the first user doc you can know the rest.

A better way is to create a Document only for storing all the user ids upon creation. This will allow you to get all users in 1 read every time.